# Writing a Code for 3D tic tac toe. Don't know how to sum lines with given lines array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to do a 3D tic-tac-toe game, and I've gotten user input down, but I'm working on the computer playing. I want to sum the lines and transverse this array to see if any of the lines equal 15. (X = 5) in the code. So anytime the user has 3 X's in a row it adds to 15 and I want the computer to block the 4th X. How would I sum my lines and traverse this 76 line array that includes all possible lines winning combinations could be on?
[First part of my code including part of the 76 line array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baw02.png)

Also, how would I make it so if a number is entered twice it prompts the computer/player to use a different number?

Comment: You probably don't want to hardcode all of that

Answer (score 2):

No. Take a step back. That's not how you want to do it.

Forget the array of possibilities. It's not necessary. What you want is an algorithm. Every space in the game has three coordinates (x, y, and z). You can create the game domain using 1-to-3 loops for each coordinate. Then, the algorithm you want is basically this:

1) A player makes a move. Use 1-to-3 loops to check the full spectrum of spaces surrounding that move. If a space is "outside" the game domain (i.e., less than 1 or greater than 3) then ignore it. If not and it matches the player's gamepiece (X or O), it's part of a 2-move line.

2) When you find a 2-move line, check the spaces (in this case, precisely 2) directly beyond that line. If it is outside the game domain, ignore it. If it matches the player's gamepiece (X or O), the player won. If it does not match and is in the game domain, then place the computer's gamepiece in that space.

Trust me that if you try the brute force approach (testing every possible combination) you'll back yourself into a corner. There is almost always an algorithm to make the problem simple.

Comment: @John: Actually, what they are supposed to do is an algorithm, too. I admit, though, a very inefficient one...

Answer (score 1):

At very first, I'm not going to write the code for you. Instead, I will *explain* what you are supposed to do (still I agree with John, this is not efficient at all):

First, what does lines represent? Imagine you had the following two classes:

```java
class Point3D
{
    public int[] coordinates = new int[3];
}
class Line
{
    public Point[] points = new Point[4];
}
```

Then you would have:

```java
Line[] lines = new Line[76];
```

`int[][][] lines` just leaves out the classes and collapses all the information into a single three-dimensional array (probably you got this already...).

Then there is an obvious relationship between `lines[i]` (containing an int[][]!) and `sums[i]`: You will be iterating over the lines and set the sum you calculated at the corresponding position in the sums array:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i)
{
    sums[i] = summate(lines[i]);
}
```

Actually, you really could write a method 'summate', if you wanted, which would have as signature `int summate(int[][] line)`.

Then you iterate over the line positions;

`for(int j = 0; j < lines[i].length; ++j)`

where you add the appropriate value to the sum:

```java
 int x = lines[i][j][0];
 int y = lines[i][j][1];
 int z = lines[i][j][2];
 int fieldValue = board[x][y][z];
 int value = 0; //calculate yourself...
```

Of course, you can access the board directly:

```java
 int fieldValue = board[lines[i][j][0]] [lines[i][j][1]] [lines[i][j][2]];
```

Decide yourself, if it reads nicely with so many index operators combined...

OK, one important hint, yet:

If you decide to do it all in two loops directly, do not forget to set sums[i] to 0 first, as it will contain the value from the previous calculation(!):

```java
for(...) // i
{
    sums[i] = 0;
    for(...) // j
    {
        sums[i] += ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to iterate over the points within the line (second dimension of the array), using their coordinates (third dimension) to check which value is to be found at the game board. I do not know which values the game board is to contain, possibly you can add them directly to the sum, possibly you have to do some calculation first (`value = board[x][y][z] == 'X' ? 5 : 0;`) for the former case simply: `for(int j = 0; j < lines[i].length; ++j) sums[i] += board[x][y][z];`

Comment: Sorry for late response - was on excursion with the kids... The board array is the representaion of your game board/field where you place the 'X's and 'O's. In your case, yes, I would assume that you will have 0 (null/zero) for nothing placed and 5 or 1 for X and O respectively. This makes calculation easiest, though not necessarily the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Define projected sums for the 3 dimensions.

```
int[][] sum_X = new int[4][4];
int[][] sum_Y = new int[4][4];
int[][] sum_Z = new int[4][4];
int[] sum_Cube_Diagnoal = new int[4];
```

At each move [x, y, z], maintain the above 4 sums,

```
sum_X[y][z] += 5; sum_Y[x][z] += 5; sum_Z[x][y] += 5;
//Need Diagnoal's algorithm to update sum_Cub_Diagnoal
```